# Adding OAuth2 to iOS Project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, oauth

I am really struggling trying to get OAuth2 into a project. I have looked at all the different OAuth clients, but the documentation is minimal and the sample projects are outdated. All I want to do is get an auth token with my clientID and secret hardcoded in and using ARC/storyboards.

I've tried OAuthConsumer, LROAuth2Client, GTM-OAuth2, OAuth2Client by nxtbgthng. Any tutorials, basic sample apps, or such you could point me to would be great. The only sample apps I can find are old, and not using ARC or storyboards.

Comment: I got an working implemetation of LROAuth2Client. Can't you modify LROAuth2Client to being ARC- compatible? In that case I can help you

Comment: The newest version of LROAuth2Client (as of 19 days ago) is fully ARC Compatible now. I still am struggling to get it implemented though.

Comment: Ok what are you struggling with?

Comment: When I call `[oauthClient authorizeUsingWebView:self.myWebView];` my app crashes. I have tried all my caveman debugging techniques, and that line is causing the issues.

Comment: I think it's because somehow the webView(myWebView) gets released after allocating it in the init-method. I put a retain on it:

Answer (score 2):

```
 - (id)init{
    self =  [super init];
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    /*****OAUTHCLIENT SETUP*****/
    oauthClient = [[SBOAuth2Client alloc] initWithClientID:@"foo" secret:@"foo" redirectURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://foo.com/"]];
    oauthClient.userURL  = [NSURL URLWithString:userUrl];
    oauthClient.tokenURL = [NSURL URLWithString:tokenUrl];
    oauthClient.delegate = self; 

    /*****WEBVIEW SETUP*****/
    webView = [[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 460)] retain];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As in:

```
 webView = [[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 460)] retain];
```

or

```
 if(webView==nil){
    //allocate it again
 }
 [oauthClient authorizeUsingWebView:webView];
```

Comment: Hmm...I tried making my webView strong, basically ARC's equivalent of retain, and it still has the issue. Any chance you have a basic implementation I could see the project? I'll upload my attempts to a git repo shortly.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/mikezehrer/TestApp2) is a github repo of what isn't working for me.

Comment: I'm looking at your ViewController.m and I can't see instantiating myWebView.

Comment: It is instantiated in the storyboard in that version. I have also tried to instantiate it in code with:     `UIWebView *newWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 460)];
    [self.view addSubview:newWebView];
    [oauthClient authorizeUsingWebView:newWebView];`

Comment: I did and I'm still not able to get it to work. I know I am just doing something small and stupid wrong, but it is frustrating as all heck!

Comment: I know, can you post your stacktrace?

Comment: I figured it out. The API I was using requires the URL to be formatted  different than the LROAuth2Client was doing it. I had to rewrite the method `- (NSURLRequest *)userAuthorizationRequestWithParameters:(NSDictionary *)additionalParameters;` and that cleared thing up.  Thanks for all your help.